# Javascript implement event onkeypress from another onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 input elements. i want to use **onkeyup** event to get the value from the first input and copy it to the third input. But I still get an empty value in the third input when i typed in the first one. The function changethree() does not automatically get value from input second when user typed in input first. Please help me

```html
<html>
<input type="text" id="satu" onkeyup="changetwo(this)" placeholder="input 1">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="dua" onkeyup="changethree(this)" placeholder="input 2"><br><br>

<input type="text" id="tiga" placeholder="input 3">

<script>
 function changetwo(a){
  var target = document.getElementById('dua');
  
  target.value = a.value;
 }
 function changethree(a){
  var target = document.getElementById('tiga');
  
  target.value = a.value;
 }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changethree()` only fires when the user types something into `dua`.  If you want `tiga` to be updated when you type in `satu` you have to add to its keyup event:

```
<input type="text" id="satu" onkeyup="changetwo(this); changethree(this)" placeholder="input 1">
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But how to fix this if i cannot change the input first, do you have another solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you saying that you can't change the HTML, or you can't type in the input field?

Comment: If you can change the javascript then do that instead.